# Can't go to the next Activity by button

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I want to set a button which when it gets clicked you will be redirected to the next Activity, But when I click on it in the emulator or my real device, it won't proceed to the next Activity,
Here's my code:

```
package com.testing.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pagetwo.class));

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

what shall I do?

Comment: Check AndroidManifest, Pagetwo Activity needs to be declared in AndroidManifest, is it declared?

Comment: What error do you get? please post logcat

Comment: @Payeli Yes I have declared Pagetwo Activity

Comment: Post Your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error then --Have you declared Contentview(XML) in your pagetwo.class?